# How can I place a JTable inside a JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

Here is my code:

```
    String col[] = {"No","Name","Capacity"};
    final DefaultTableModel tablemodel = new DefaultTableModel(col,0);      

    Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
    JTable table = new JTable(tablemodel);
    table.setBounds(414, 39, 294, 281);
    contentPane.add(table);
    contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(table));

    JButton btnCreateTheMovie = new JButton("Create the movie theater");        
    btnCreateTheMovie.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            movietheater.addMovieTheater(addtheaterID.getText(), Integer.parseInt(addtheater_capacity.getText()));
            try {
                write_movie_theater = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("d:/movietheater.txt"),true));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            };  

                int x = movietheater.movietheater_array.size()-1;
                i++;
                String ID = movietheater.movietheater_array.get(x).getID();
                int capacity = movietheater.movietheater_array.get(x).getCapacity();

                Object[] data = {i,ID,capacity};
                tablemodel.addRow(data);                    
        }
    });
    btnCreateTheMovie.setBounds(75, 192, 166, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnCreateTheMovie,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

I ran this code, but the JTtable is not visible. How can I add JScrollpane to JList? 
How can i see the jtable headers?

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2):

[JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) by default uses [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) that adds only single component in each segment (north, south, center, west, east). Please have a look at [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).

### Remember:

- Don't use `setBounds()` method just hand over it to Layout Manager to set the size and position of the components that what it is made for.
- Use [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) instead of [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) for `JButton`
- Avoid `null` layout at all that uses *absolute positioning* and you must specify the size and position of every component within that container. One **drawback of absolute positioning** is that it does not adjust well when the top-level container is resized. It also does not adjust well to differences between users and systems, such as different font sizes and locales.

---

Try it again after making some changes:

- no need to add the `JTable` in the contentPane because it's already added in `JScrollPane`
- simply add the `JScrollPane` in the center of the `JFrame`
- add the `JButton` either in north or south as per your need.

Sample code:

```
String col[] = { "No", "Name", "Capacity" };
DefaultTableModel tablemodel = new DefaultTableModel(col, 0);

Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
JTable table = new JTable(tablemodel);
contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(table));

JButton btnCreateTheMovie = new JButton("Create the movie theater");
contentPane.add(btnCreateTheMovie, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

snapshot:

[image]

Comment: it will be fine. Thank you

Comment: When i do your changes, my jtable is unvisible.I can't understand why it is?

Comment: i edited my code and it didn't work again.If i put the actionlistener instead of mouse listener i can't do what i want.

Comment: I have already tested your code. it's working. Post complete code or look what you have missed. you are using `setBounds()` methods again.

Comment: No i didn't it's a comment line.

Comment: look at `table.setBounds(414, 39, 294, 281);`

Comment: I ask it again What is not working? Is the `JFrame` not visible or what is displayed or ...

Comment: Jtable is not visible

Comment: If i put the setbounds button is visible.But now it's not.

Comment: Are you setting `null` layout for `JFrame` something like `setLayout(null);` Always avoid it. Read the post carefully. I mentioned it in first line.

Comment: Yes i did likte that.

Comment: Thank you.But design is break.

Comment: Because you are using absolute positioning using `null` layout. read at my post again and re-design you application with the proper layout manager.

Comment: Thank you for all your help and sorry about my faults.

Comment: not at all my friend. :) Just follow the links that I shared you.